# ranges-v3 join function to join two containers together

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

I've been trying to understand the Range-v3 [`join`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1join__view.html) documentation but I'll be honest, I don't understand it. And I've not been able to find any relevant examples either.

Could someone show me how to create a joined view of two deque vectors please. I've already tried these methods but to no avail.

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

struct data_t
{
    int data;
    int some_other_data;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace ranges;

    auto v1 = std::deque<data_t>() = { {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5} };
    auto v2 = std::deque<data_t>() = { {6,6}, {7,7}, {8,8}, {9,9}, {10,10} };

    auto vv = v1 | ranges::actions::join(v2);
    // auto vv = ranges::actions::join(v1, v2);   // Tried this too

    for(auto v : vv)
    {
        std::cout << v.data << ", " << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a [live](https://godbolt.org/z/WrzzG8hx5) demo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a general suggestion, whenever you want the documentation for something which is in Range-v3, you better pray it is in C++20 too and refer to that. That's the case for [`join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view) (but not for `concat`, apparently).

You're looking for `concat`, not `join`:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using ranges::views::concat;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> w{4,5,6};
    std::cout << concat(v,w) << std::endl; // prints [1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

`join` is for something else, namely collapsing two nested ranges:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using ranges::views::join;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> w{{1,2,3},{4},{5,6}};
    std::cout << (w | join) << std::endl; // prints [1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

Notice that `join` (which is called `join` in some other languages too, like Haskell, and `flatten` somewhere else) is a very important concept in functional programming.

Indeed, when I write *collapsing two nested **ranges***, I'm being fairly approximative, because [Haskell's `join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) (or the true meaning of `join`/`flatten`/whatever is called in category theory) is much more profound than that. For instance, in Haskell it's true that `join (Just (Just 3)) == Just 3`, which in C++ you'd write as

```cpp
std::optional<std::optional<int>>{3} | join /* not Range-v3's */ == std::optional<int>{3}
```

What Haskell's `join` really does is *collapsing two nested **monads***. For reference in C++, you might want to give a look at [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) and specifically at the documentation of the [`Monad`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Monad.html) concept.

Comment: You can write `concat` in terms of `join`, at a sketch: `auto concat(auto& head, auto&... tail) { std::array<decltype(first) *, 1 + sizeof...(tail)> nested{ &head, &tail... }; return nested | deref | join; }`